# CodeIgniter on live site not loading controller class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to setup my site on a production server, and it's basically crashing at line 291 in /system/core/CodeIgniter.php:

```
//instantiate the requested controller

// Mark a start point so we can benchmark the controller
$BM->mark('controller_execution_time_( '.$class.' / '.$method.' )_start');

$CI = new $class();
```

The class is 'auth' (from the tank_auth library), so it's crashing on '$CI = new auth();'

It doesn't produce an error (why??), just displays a blank page. This all works fine locally.

Has anyone had any similar issues?

Comment: if this is linux, have you double checked permissions?

Comment: Sanity checks: 1) @Jakub's suggestion--permissions, 2) case sensitivity in file names and class names, 3) harder stuff; let us know when you get here

Comment: I'm having the same issues on an AWS EC2 instance. Do you by chance remember what the solve was?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I fixed that by installing the php-mysql package:

$ sudo yum install php-mysql

Comment: This fix my problem, dont know why.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked if error reporting is enabled? If not, try adding

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to the beginning of index.php.

Answer (score 2):

Check this thread for similar issue: [CodeIgniter project loads blank webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486872/codeigniter-project-loads-blank-webpage)

Also, in case you *don't* have mysql installed and/or a database set up for your site, TankAuth *does* need the database. Be sure to follow all the [installation instructions](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) and create the tables that the module needs (you'll see a .sql dump in the downloaded folder).

Answer (score 1):

see the include_path in php on your production server and/or make other frontend with development environment to see error

Comment: Hey sly, I'm not sure it's an include_path thing specific to php. This all works fine locally, and codeigniter's files are loading properly...
Also the production environment is basically a development environment at this point.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, in my case i needed install de lib php-pgsql(because i use postgresql) on my server. After that, the problem was solved

Comment: Can you develop your answer more? It's an old question with some answers already. Can be nice to hear your solution but more explained.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was the same than the others, install mysql compatibility to php. In my case the platform is ubuntu on Amazon AWS (Using mysql on RDS, not local):

`$sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

`$sudo apt-get install mysql-client`

`$sudo service apache2 restart`

And thats is all, Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Add same issue on Cpanel , moving a CI project from php 5.3 to 5.4

Blank page or 500 internal server error

This resolve the issue :

Enable the "mysqli" extension in PHP (v5) via EasyApache, using the Exhaustive Options List (Cpanel).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was fixed by doing this:

```
   yum install php-mysqli
```

on Centos 8